# pythonic conditional aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, aggregation

I have a large Dataframe with > 3000 category labels.  I'd like to selectively re-code labels based on groupby counts. This is like a conditional replace in Excel.  For example:

```
ID Label   
1  cat  
2  dog  
3  cat  
4  cat  
5  dog  
6  bird
```

count of each:

```
cat: 3  
dog: 2  
bird: 1
```

logic: if count <= 2, then change label to 'other'

```
ID Label   
1  cat  
2  other  
3  cat  
4  cat  
5  other  
6  other
```

count of each:

```
cat: 3  
other: 3
```

Perhaps some of you know a more pythonic way to accomplish the same thing. maybe the mysterious lambda function can help...

already read a bunch of posts here, as usual.

My meager Python code looks like this:

```
df['Label'] = df.groupby('Label')['Label'].transform('count')
df['New_Label'] = np.where(df.label <= 2, 'other', df.label)
```

Comment: are the pandas dataframes ?

Comment: yes.  this is all being done with Pandas.  apologies for the bad formatting above, let me try and fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses `pd.DataFrame.where()` instead of `np.where()` and does it in one line:

```
df.Label = df.Label.where(df.groupby('Label')['Label'].transform('count') > 2, 'other')
print(df)
```

```
     Label
ID       
1      cat
2    other
3      cat
4      cat
5    other
6    other
```